# Why is the WPF property IsDefaulted not found?

Tags: c#, wpf, templates, button, styles

I was working on my button template with this example: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms753328.aspx

I found the "IsDefaulted" property quite useful, but can't use it.
I have the following trigger setup:

```
<ControlTemplate.Triggers>                      
    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
        <Setter TargetName="Presenter" Property="BitmapEffect">
            <Setter.Value>
                <OuterGlowBitmapEffect GlowColor="White" Opacity="0.2" />
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Trigger>

    <Trigger Property="IsDefaulted" Value="true">
        <Setter TargetName="Canvas" Property="Height" Value="40" />
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="18" />
    </Trigger>
</ControlTemplate.Triggers>
```

However, on build, I get:

> Cannot find the Template Property 'IsDefaulted' on the type 'System.Windows.Controls.Control'.

Which is strange, because Google doesn't tell me anything about this, nor does MSDN or anything else.
After some testing, I figured that:

-IsMouseOver: Works

-IsPressed: Doesn't work

-IsDefaulted: Doesn't work

-IsKeyboardFocused: Works

-IsEnabled: Works

Bug? Something I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Got it fixed:

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
```

As simple as that :)

Comment: OMG THANK YOU! Just wasted 2 days and this just worked!